# Disable OpenGL Profiler's "Attach" feature

Tags: macos, debugging, opengl, profiling, osx-mountain-lion

On my Mac OS X 10.8, I've used the Apple's OpenGL Profiler and (as instructed on [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/OpenGLProfilerUserGuide/GettedStarted/GettingStarted.html)) I set the GL_ENABLE_DEBUG_ATTACH and log'ed out/in. After setting that I immediately noticed that most apps that use OpenGL (such as the browser) became slower and thus I wanted to undo it.

The problem is that even after removing the GL_ENABLE_DEBUG_ATTACH from the ~/.profile and from the ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist and restarting, it seems that the "debug attach" feature is still enabled "somewhere", since the OpenGL Profiler does not present any error (as it should if the GL_ENABLE_DEBUG_ATTACH was not undefined). On the terminal, an echo $GL_ENABLE_DEBUG_ATTACH does not print anything.

Do I need to do anything else to disable OpenGL profiling?

Update: Another interesting finding is that when debugging with XCode, when I pause the execution of an OpenGL app there is an "OGL Profiler" thread in the thread's list.

Update2: This does not happen on a new User on the same machine.

Comment: What is your output of: `declare | grep GL_ENABLE_DEBUG_ATTACH`? I have it enabled on all of my OS X systems and have not noticed any _drastic_ reduction in performance, maybe 1-2 FPS at most. In the worst case, you could probably edit `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` to read: <key> **GL_ENABLE_DEBUG_ATTACH** </key><string> **NO** </string>

Comment: declare | grep GL_ENABLE_DEBUG_ATTACH does not print anything. Also, I already have GL_ENABLE_DEBUG_ATTACH set to NO in environment.plist.

Comment: I saw your flag, but I'm not so sure this needs to be moved to Apple.SE. This is a developer tool, and you're asking to use it in a development context, so I think this fits here just fine.

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm facing similar issue on OSX 10.10

Comment: No I haven't. I still have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this thread is old, but an answer may still be relevant.

Once you check in (recent) OGL Profiler, you can never leave ..

```
defaults read com.apple.opengl
```

on my Macbook returns:

```
{
    DebugAttachEnable = 1;
}
```

Just set it to zero and profiling thread will disappear:

```
defaults write com.apple.opengl DebugAttachEnable 0
```

Have fun!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the same machine where I enabled OpenGL debug attach, and I dare not enabling it on my current machine, so I cannot really test this :(

Comment: I can confirm that this does in fact prevent the "OGL Profiler" thread from infesting every application I open, after a system reboot.